# How to clone a specific folder of remote repo from git in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

How to clone a specific folder of remote repo from git in jenkins pipeline ? I want it to be as part of my Jenkinsfile. I dont want the method of additional behavious, but want to write code as part of Jenkinsfile. Thanks.

Comment: what is the use case to clone specific folder when entire repo is cloned?

Comment: I dont want to clone the entire repo because its very huge, I just want to clone a folder which has some scripts that I want to run